# Слетает Path для Java при перезапуске ПК на Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, path

Java Path настроен и всё работает,но при перезапуске ПК слетает,пример:
включаю ПК,и при попытке скомпилировать/запустить программу/узнать версию java или компилятора получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лечиться это так: просто захожу в переменные среды и просто нажимаю ок,ничего не меняя,всё начинает работать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка номер 2 и теперь всё работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь всё работает как надо,при перезагрузке ПК всё продолжает работать,но если выключить ПК и затем включить,то опять возникает та же проблема.Собственно проблема не критичная,просто надоело после каждого включения ПК в переменные среды заходить.Кто знает,в чём может быть проблема?Вот моя JAVA_HOME:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И Path:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы уверены, что под учетной-записью администратора заходите?

Comment: вероятно, при занрузке значение `Path` инициализируется до инициализации `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @And учётная запись администратора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снеси java и снова установи!Т.е. все включая и JDK, JRE.

Comment: Делал уже,не помогло

Comment: а у тебя системный диск D что-ли ?

Comment: и bin сотри в конце пути к java!!!! не (D:\progs\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin), а (D:\progs\Java\jdk1.8.0_162)

Comment: указал путь без bin,теперь компилятор вообще работать перестал,вернул обратно bin,системный диск С,просто это ссд и я его чисто для системы использую,а на D создал каталог где jdk,jre,сорсы, документация,и там же сами программы,мне так просто удобнее когда всё в 1 папке

Comment: Так а какой у тебя диск системный C или D? надо в системный ставить! https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/ Почитай тут

Comment: На ссд такая идея не зайдет, так как после отключения (если он под ос) все последние изменения не сохраняются!

Comment: тогда просто снести jdk и переставить на диск C?

Comment: Ну да, только на физический жестки, на котором основная система стоит! А если ты юзаешь для занятий программированием ссд, то тогда придется всегда при включении пути прописывать!

Comment: Ну так диск С это ссд с системой,D это жёсткий,под хранилище, на котором сейчас java находится,тогда получается смысла менять пути нету,раз всё равно слетать будет.Ладно,спасибо что разъяснили в чём проблема)

Comment: Если этот ссд не переносной а в компе стоит как основной диск с системой, то на него и прописывай java, т.е на диск С! Я просто думал, что у тебя ссд переносной и типо на нем система, что бы на любом компе юзать! в таком случае как я говорил ни чего не выйдет! ну а раз он у тебя как обычный диск, то тогда просто на С все перенеси и все

Comment: Я сделал по другому,по ссылке,что вы кидали,не увидел что в %JAVA_HOME%   /bin дописан был,сейчас удалил /bin в каталоге к jdk,а в %JAVA_HOME%   /bin добавил,попробовал и перезагрузить пк и выкл/вкл сделать,в обеих случаях всё теперь работает сразу,Спасибо)Вообще не сильно критично,если я дальше буду пользоваться java через диск D?

Comment: Я думаю что нет, но все же лучше когда такие вещи на системном диске установлены!